# online grok debugger doesn't work as expected

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am pretty new to grok. Am trying to understand it by testing some grok patterns using online [Online Grok Tool](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).

I followed the instruction provided in the [Link](https://fabianlee.org/2016/07/13/logstash-testing-logstash-grok-patterns-online/) for the same.

When am testing as mentioned in the instructions link I don't see any output. please see below for error,

```
127.0.0.1 – – [11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800] “GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1” 200 3891 “http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php” “Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0”
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you copy/pasted the log directly from website, which copied html entity characters.

observe how `– –` are not `- -`, and `“ ”` are not `" "` in the following log,

```
127.0.0.1 – – [11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800] “GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1” 200 3891 “http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php” “Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0”
```

Following should work fine,

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Dec/2013:00:01:45 -0800] "GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3891 "http://cadenza/xampp/navi.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
```